# What information is encoded in discriminant varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I'm looking for Web-accessible references that survey the connnections among the following constructs:

1. discriminant varieties
2. Vandermonde matrix/determinant/polynomial
3. moment curves for the n-simplices, the cyclic polytopes
4. Legendre-Fenchel transform/compositional inversion
5. Lagrangian-Hamiltonian duality,

something along the lines of "[How tangents solve algebraic equations, or a remarkable geometry of discriminant varieties](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211281)" by Katz and a little more pedestrian than say "[Simple Lie algebras and Legendre varieties](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~mukai/)" by Mukai.

(One example of info that can be easily decoded from relations among 1,2,4, and 5 is the convergence limit for the Taylor series expansions of the solutions about the origin of the family of equations

$$y=x+t \cdot x^n,$$

whose coefficients are the Fuss-Catalan numbers.)